# Get intents, entities, contexts and all data

Tags: javascript, rest, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In the case, the actually conversation-simple have one function with all the values, but the function update every time if flows conversation.

I want create one function or other form to be able to capture all that data that is currently on the data.

In the case have Intents, context, entities, etc.

```
conversation.message(payload, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
    }
    return res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));
  });
});
```

The data inside updateMessage parameter have all I need, but if I create other function and try get this values, does not work.

In the case I use the values and get with app.js for open some REST webservice.
I try it:

```
function login (req, res) {    
      numberOrigin = null;
      sessionid = null;

      var dataLogin = {
        data:  { "userName":"xxxxx","password":"xxxxx","platform":"MyPlatform" },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      };

      client.registerMethod("postMethod", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/services/login", "POST");        
      client.methods.postMethod(dataLogin, function (data, response) {

        if(Buffer.isBuffer(data)){
          data = data.toString('utf8');
          console.log(data);
          var re = /(sessionID: )([^,}]*)/g;
          var match = re.exec(data);
          var sessionid = match[2]
          console.log(sessionid);              
        }
      });
    }

    function openRequest(data, sessionid, numberOrigin ){
      //console.log(data); dont show the values.. show the data response of login
         var dataRequest = {
         data: {"sessionID": sessionid,
                "synchronize":false,
        "sourceRequest":{
             "numberOrigin":numberOrigin,
             "description": JSON.stringify(data.context.email) } },
         headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
         };

         numberOrigin +=1;
         client.post("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/services/request/create", dataRequest, function (data, response) {         
          if(Buffer.isBuffer(data)){
          data = data.toString('utf8');    
          console.log(data);          
          }
        });
      }

    function updateMessage(res, input, data, numberOrigin) {
      var email = data.context.email;  // this recognize but this function is responsible for other thing        
       if (email === 'xxxxxxxxxxxx@test.com') {
        console.log(data);
        login(data);
        openRequest(data, sessionid, numberOrigin)
       }
     }
```

In case, I just want `get` the values with my `app.js` for use inside REST. I got it with `ajax` but everything on the client side (index.html), and that made me show my credentials, so I decided to do it in REST for security my code..
If have some form to solved this, please let me know. 
If have other form to do it, I'll be happy to know.

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely that you need to write to the response object `res`.. In the updateMessage function the response is passed in. In order for data to be sent back to the browser you need to write to the response. I have a demo app which calls the weather channel to get the weather based on an intent, similar to what you are trying to do with your login function. Please take a look at this code
https://github.com/doconnor78/conversation-simple-weather/blob/master/app.js#L130

You will need to pass the original res (response) object into the appropriate function and then write data to the response (res) once you get it from the third party service.